# Date and time transition from data with line

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, charts, transition

I created this chart using D3 V5. Also, I have attached the sample data on the fiddle you can [view by clicking here](https://plnkr.co/edit/pINxcS9yt9AuJmSk02Fs?p=preview).

I've included the `tick` function code block which appends new domains for x and y scales and line/data on the path to slide left:

When the tick function executes, the line sort of rebuilds which makes it look like it bounces.
How can it be smooth, without a bounce at all when it rebuilds the line?

```js
var tr = d3
  .transition()
  .duration(obj.tick.duration)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear);

function tick() {
  return setInterval(function() {
    var newData = [];
    var tickFunction = obj.tick.fnTickData;
    if (tickFunction !== undefined && typeof tickFunction === "function") {
      newData = tickFunction();
      for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
        obj.data.push(newData[i]);
      }
    }

    if (newData.length > 0) {
      var newMaxDate, newMinDate, newDomainX;
      if (isKeyXDate) {
        newMaxDate = new Date(
          Math.max.apply(
            null,
            obj.data.map(function(e) {
              return new Date(e[obj.dataKeys.keyX]);
            })
          )
        );
        newMinDate = new Date(
          Math.min.apply(
            null,
            obj.data.map(function(e) {
              return new Date(e[obj.dataKeys.keyX]);
            })
          )
        );
        newDomainX = [newMinDate, newMaxDate];
      } else {
        newDomainX = [
          d3.min(obj.data, function(d) {
            return d[obj.dataKeys.keyX];
          }),
          d3.max(obj.data, function(d) {
            return d[obj.dataKeys.keyX];
          })
        ];
      }

      // update the domains
      //x.domain([newMinDate, newMaxDate]);
      if (obj.tick.updateXDomain) {
        newDomainX = obj.tick.updateXDomain;
      }
      x.domain(newDomainX);
      if (obj.tick.updateYDomain) {
        y.domain(obj.tick.updateYDomain);
      }

      path.attr("transform", null);

      // slide the line left
      if (obj.area.allowArea) {
        areaPath.attr("transform", null);
        areaPath
          .transition()
          .transition(tr)
          .attr("d", area);
      }
      path
        .transition()
        .transition(tr)
        .attr("d", line);
      svg
        .selectAll(".x")
        .transition()
        .transition(tr)
        .call(x.axis);
      svg
        .selectAll(".y")
        .transition()
        .transition(tr)
        .call(y.axis);

      // pop the old data point off the front
      obj.data.shift();
    }
  }, obj.tick.tickDelay);
}
this.interval = tick();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gerardo notes, transitioning the `d` attribute of the path won't work very well unless you modfiy the approach. Here's a simple example of the sort of wiggle/bouncing that will arise if simply updating the `d` attribute of the path:

[image]

Pᴏɪɴᴛs ᴛʀᴀɴsɪᴛɪᴏɴɪɴɢ ᴀᴄʀᴏss sᴄʀᴇᴇɴ, ᴡɪᴛʜ ᴘᴀᴛʜ ᴛʀᴀɴsɪᴛɪᴏɴɪɴɢ ғʀᴏᴍ ᴏɴᴇ ᴅᴀᴛᴀ sᴇᴛ ᴛᴏ ᴛʜᴇ ɴᴇxᴛ.

The above behavior is noted by Mike Bostock in a short piece [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), and here's a snippet reproducing the above animation:

```js
var n = 10;
var data = d3.range(n).map(function(d) {
  return {x: d, y:Math.random() }
})

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .range([10,490])
  
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([290,10]);
  
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height", 400)
  .append("g");
  
var path = svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", line);

var points = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data, function(d) { return d.x; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("r", 5);


function tick() {
 
  var transition = d3.transition()
    .duration(1000);
  
  var newPoint = {x:n++, y: Math.random() };
  data.shift()
  data.push(newPoint);
  
  x.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d) { return d.x; }))
  
  points = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data, function(d) { return d.x; })
    
   points.exit()
     .transition(transition)
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); }) 
     .remove(); 
     
  points.enter().append("circle")
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x)+30; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
     .merge(points)
     .transition(transition)
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
     .attr("r", 5);

  path.datum(data)
    .transition(transition)
    .attr("d", line)
    .on("end", tick);
}

tick();
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

One solution to this wiggle/bounce is:

1. add an additional point(s) to the data,
2. redraw the line with the recently added to data array
3. find out the next extent of the data
4. transition the line to the left
5. update the scale and transition the axis
6. remove the first data point(s)

This is also proposed in Mike's article that I've linked to. Here would be a basic implementation with your code:

*I've avoided a setInterval function by recursively calling the function at the end of the last transition*:

```
    function slide() {
     // Stop any ongoing transitions:
     d3.selectAll().interrupt();

      // A transition:
      var transition = d3.transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)

      // 1. add an additional point(s) to the data
      var newData = obj.tick.fnTickData();
      obj.data.push(...newData);

      // 2. redraw the line with the recently added to data array
      path.datum(obj.data)
      areaPath.datum(obj.data)

      // Redraw the graph, without the translate, with less data:
      path.attr("transform","translate(0,0)")
        .attr("d", line)

      areaPath.attr("transform","translate(0,0)")
        .attr("d", area)          

      // 3. find out the next extent of the data                     
      // Assuming data is in chronological order:
      var min = obj.data[newData.length][obj.dataKeys.keyX];
      var max = obj.data[obj.data.length-1][obj.dataKeys.keyX];

      // 4. transition the line to the left
      path.datum(obj.data)
        .transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(-x(new Date(min)))+",0)");
      areaPath.datum(obj.data)
        .transition(transition)
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(-x(new Date(min)))+",0)");

      // 5. update the scale and transition the axis
      x.domain([new Date(min),new Date(max)])

      // Update the xAxis:
      svg.selectAll('.x')
         .transition(transition)
         .call(x.axis)
         .on("end",slide); // Trigger a new transition at the end.

      // 6. remove the first data point(s)  
      obj.data.splice(0,newData.length)
    }
    slide();
```

Here's an updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HItwx6Zpwmam2AX58yVd?p=preview).

Comment: I observed much from the code, Thanks it gave me quiet knowledge and good explanation and so did Gerardo too. Though i wanted to ask few things i found new. "`data.push(...newData)`"  especially 3 pre-dots, i'm reading about it.

Comment: one more question for understanding, `line: 269`, `var min = obj.data[newData.length][obj.dataKeys.keyX];` why did you consider it as minimum and not as maximum? I was thinking that last received data should be the max(i now know i was wrong but can you give me the logic behind this? please.)

Comment: The `...` (javascript spread operator) is so that if there are multiple new points, each one is pushed individually (`newData = [a,b]`, `data.push(...newData)` is the same as `data.push(a), data.push(b)` or `data.push(a,b)`. Also, the new min should be nudged n spots over from where it was, where n is the number of new data points. If `newData.length` ==1 (n ==1), `obj.data[newData.length]` is the second data item: after we remove the first item (with data.splice), the second data item will be the first.

Comment: thank you so much, my bad for misunderstanding it there. You're getting the index 1  from `obj.data` using `newData.Length` which is off-course 1.

Answer (score 3):

That *bounce* is actually the expected result when you transition the `d` attribute, which is just a string.

There are several solutions here. Without refactoring your code too much, a simple one is using the `pathTween` function written by Mike Bostock in this bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3916621. Here, I'm changing it a little bit so you can pass the datum, like this:

```
path.transition()
    .transition(tr)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        var self = this;
        var thisd = line(d);
        return pathTween(thisd, 1, self)()
    })
```

Here is the forked plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aAqpdSb9JozwHsErpqa9?p=preview

Comment: the plunker you provided is not really working well i.e. path's transition to left. Can't it be smooth and without a bounce at all?

Comment: can you tell me the points where i can make changes in my code to make it smoother? i'll do that and thanks for sharing "path tween" its a new knowledge to me, but it is not helping me out in this scenario though.

Comment: *"Can't it be smooth and without a bounce at all?"*... in that case you have a **different question**. I just answered your question, doing the same transition, but without the *bouce* effect. I suggest you edit your question, better explaining what kind of solution you expect.

Comment: appreciate your help, work and time brother and thank you so much and my apologies if i offended you in anyway. But i did add the *"how to avoid it from bouncing"*. But if it was unclear i also edited and added the smooth word with it.

Comment: @ARr0w You didn't offend me. I told you to edit your question, making it more clear, so other users can understand exactly what kind of solution you're looking for.